# Get root node of XML doc using simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

Using simplexml_load_string() how do I get "ForgotPassword" from the following XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ForgotPassword>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <authentication>
        <login>username</login>
        <apikey>login</apikey>
    </authentication>
    <parameters>
        <emailAddress>joesmith@example.com</emailAddress>
    </parameters>
</ForgotPassword>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Are you wanting to get the name of the root node?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
echo $xml->getName();
```

Comment: What about root attributes? E.g. `Artisan Chapter` from `<themes title='Artisan Chapter>'`

Comment: Just FYI it seems that getName() only became available starting with PHP 5.1.3 - so if you're getting an "undefined method SimpleXMLElement::getName()" error check your PHP version with phpinfo() or php -i on the command line.