# SimpleXML - how to get root object name?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get root node of XML doc using simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811797/get-root-node-of-xml-doc-using-simplexml)

**QUESTIONs:** I got some questions regarding XML parsing via SimpleXML. I still don't get around it completely.

- Where is my root element (config_admin) or how do i get it's name?
- Why is the config_data array nested? Even if i replace the file with config_data inside the class, i get the same result.
- What is the best way to access my elements?
- What's wrong with my doctype / element definitions?

I know it's bad habbit asking 3 Qs in one Thread, but i didn't want to bother everyone with that much repeating code samples.

I want to expend my knowledge, so every answer is welcome. Even if it comes to code styling or else. Thank you.

---

I have a xml file like the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE config_admin [
    <!ELEMENT config_admin (page,sub_page)>
        <!ELEMENT page (page_title,slug,menu_title)>
            <!ELEMENT page_title (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT slug (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT menu_title (#PCDATA)>
    ]>

    <config_admin>

    <!--
    MAIN Page
     -->
        <page>
            <page_title>OOO</page_title>
            <slug>ooo</slug>
            <menu_title>OOO</menu_title>
            <cap>manage_options</cap>
            <icon_url>OOO</icon_url>
            <position>OOO</position>

            <tabs>
                <abc_uid>abc</abc_uid>
                <def_uid>def</def_uid>
                <ghi_uid>ghi</ghi_uid>
            </tabs>

            <!-- Options for the main page -->
            <opt_group>
                <group_name>OOO</group_name>
                <opt_name>OOO</opt_name>
                <tab>ABC</tab>

                <!-- Section -->
                <section>
                    <section_title>OOO</section_title>
                    <section_UID>OOO</section_UID>

                    <!-- Defaults -->
                    <field_defaults>
                            <field_uid>Value</field_uid>
                            <_oxoxoxo>OXO</_oxoxoxo>
                            <_axaxaxa>AXA</_axaxaxa>
                            <_cxcxcxc>CXC</_cxcxcxc>
                    </field_defaults>
... etc.
```

...and parse it through using a class which does nothing than the following:

```
$data = new myXmlParser( $require_files_path.$file );
$data = (array) $data;
$config_data[] = $data;

echo '<pre>OUTPUT: <br />';
    echo '===================================================================== <br />';
    foreach ( $config_data as $key => $value) :
        print_r($value);
        echo '<br />';
    endforeach;
echo '</pre>';

// The Class i use to parse
    if ( !class_exists('myXmlParser') ) {

    class myXmlParser {
        public $file;
        public $config_data;

        public function __construct( $file ) {
            $this->file = $file;

            $this->config_data = simplexml_load_file( $this->file );
            $this->config_data = $this->recursive_parse( $this->config_data );
        }
        private function recursive_parse( $data ) {
            $output = array();
            if ( is_object($data) ){
                settype( $data, 'array' );
            }
            foreach ( $data as $key => $value ){
                if ( $key == 'comment' )
                    unset($key);
                if ( $key && $value ) :
                    if ( is_array($value) || is_object($value) ) {
                        $output[$key] = $this->recursive_parse( $value );
                    }
                    else {
                        $output[$key] = (string) $value;
                    }
                endif;
            }

            return $output;
        }
    }
    }
```

However, the output is like the following:

```
OUTPUT: 
===================================================================== 
Array
(
    [file] => R:\development\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\child_test/config_admin.xml
    [config_data] => Array
        (
            [page] => Array
                (
                    [page_title] => OXO
                    [slug] => oxo
                    [menu_title] => OXO
                    [cap] => manage_options
                    [icon_url] => OXO
                    [position] => OXO
                    [tabs] => Array
                        (
                            [abc_uid] => abc
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should remove the extraneous questions from this question and post them separately. Keeping questions short makes it easier for readers to respond.

To answer your question

> Where is my root element (config_admin) or how do i get it's name?

Your root element is returned by [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or `simplexml_load_file()`. In case you don't know its name, you can get its name with [`getName()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php). If you know its name, you should always name the variable the same name as the root element, as it makes it easier to match variables to the node they represent.

```
 $config_admin = simplexml_load_file('config.xml');
 echo $config_admin->getName();
```

Comment: It could be accessed by: $attributes = current($docs->attributes()->{'NAME'})