# php xml parser simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

simplexml_load_string() doesnot seem to work form for the following xml

```
 "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Chat_vailable queue="IBIN" locale="gn">Hide</Chat_vailable>"

$result = simplexml_load_string($response->data)

[@attributes]
  queue -> IBIN
  locale->gn
```

the above xml is part of a response so when get the result it only contains attributes

$result is an object of SimpleXMLElement and only has an array of attributes

It doesn't have anything related to "Chat_valiable" or HIDE.

Could some one help please

Comment: `Chat_vailable` is [the root node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811797/get-root-node-of-xml-doc-using-simplexml).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're using to inspect the object there, I'm guessing `print_r`, but whatever it is, don't rely on it. :)

SimpleXML does not create a real PHP object with properties for everything in the XML document, it provides an object-like API linked to the internal parsed representation.

So in your case:

- `Chat_vailable` is the root node, so is represented by `$result` itself (SimpleXML has no separate object for the "document", so there is nothing "above" the root element)
- `Hide` is the text content of that node, so can be accessed with a string cast: `(string)$result` (or just `echo $result`, since that casts to string automatically)
- the attributes `queue` and `locale` can be accessed using array notation (casting to string is a good habit, to avoid passing around objects which may confuse later functions): `(string)$result['queue']`, `(string)$result['locale']`

If you want to inspect the full content available through a SimpleXML object, have a look at [these dedicated SimpleXML debug functions](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug).

Answer (score 0):

performing `var_dump` on `$result` yield this. So it does get both attributes and content.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["queue"]=>
    string(4) "IBIN"
    ["locale"]=>
    string(2) "gn"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Hide"
}
```

code that produce the output above as follows

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Chat_vailable queue="IBIN" locale="gn">Hide</Chat_vailable>
EOF;

$result = simplexml_load_string($xml);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
echo "queue: $xml[queue], locaele: $xml[locale], value: $xml";
```

will output:

```
queue: IBIN, locaele: gn, value: Hide
```

see it working: https://eval.in/39965