# XML : PHP echo is empty

Tags: php, xml, tags

Having an issue echo'ing xml tags.

PHP:

```
$xml = $insureFormResult->returned;
$xml1 = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$result = $xml1->xpath("response")[0];
echo $result;
```

If I echo $xml it gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
  <errors>
    <error code="7">Your details are already in our system and have been forwarded to our insurance partners who will contact you shortly</error>
  </errors>
</response>
```

The xml will always have one response tag. I also want to know how to echo the tag with id 'code'. I tried the php above but there's no result echoed.

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

It wasn't working because of the version of PHP on my server.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811797/get-root-node-of-xml-doc-using-simplexml  `<response>` is the root node of your example, and SimpleXML won't traverse it.  `xpath("/response")` will work.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thanks for the link, was just searching for the dupe.

Comment: @msbodetti You will find more documentation and help about SimpleXML here: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: @hakre And I was searching for the docs which explain this before I CV'd

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I already tried that and it is blank as well..

Comment: @msbodetti You should get something... http://codepad.viper-7.com/gHFD6L

Comment: I know I should get a response because if I take away [0] it echos Array. It's just empty on my side.. so I don't understand what's the issue.

Comment: 1) Do you have display_errors enabled? 2) Are you using PHP 5.4 or later? You need 5.4 for array dereferencing a function call `()[]`.  If you get no output, you might actually have a fatal error.  `echo $response[0]->errors->error;`  returns your string. http://codepad.viper-7.com/62FVWb

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that worked.. I guess it's a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with PHP, but the xpath to access the error with attribute `code` with value `7` is:

```
/response/errors/error[@code='7']
```